# Custom views canvas

Tags: java, android, layout

I have this problems with custom views canvas :

1-How can I reset my view after doing changes? This is my code but nothing happens

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int viewWidthHalf = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    int viewHeightHalf = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    int radius;
    if (viewWidthHalf > viewHeightHalf)
        radius = viewHeightHalf - 10;
    else
        radius = viewWidthHalf - 10;
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, paint);
}

public void setbackground(int backgroundColor) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    invalidate();
}
```

2-How can i get canvas in other methods?

3-When I'm drawCircle with the code above circle has an 0.3-0.4 alpha. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-  Try doing this:

```
       @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int viewWidthHalf = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2; 
    int viewHeightHalf = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    int radius; 
    if (viewWidthHalf > viewHeightHalf)
        radius = viewHeightHalf - 10;
    else
        radius = viewWidthHalf - 10;

   // All lines above would go better in the onCreate Method
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, paint);
    invalidate();
}
```

2- You possibly won't need that

3- What controls this is the **paint** you are using to draw the circle. I can't see what's happening only trough this snippet of code, but you should start looking what could be giving an alpha to your paint.

Comment: invalidate(); didnt change the color of circle and protected void onDraw() you write in the code doesn't seems right

Comment: What value are you giving to the backgroundColor variable?